# Moving from Germany to UK

Tags: united-kingdom, stateless

I am Adeniyi. I have lived in Germany for three years but I am stateless. 
I want to move to live with my partner and my son; both live in London.

My question is according to the questionnaire read from UK embassy talk of stateless/Refugees

1. What is Article 10 mean and
2. Did I need a letter ? ( from my partner)

Once I don’t have any document

*From OP response in answer*

She is registered and work in London, we haven’t get married yet ... She is an Austria citizen...why my son registered with my name in Uk

Comment: Is your partner an EU citizen?  Is your partnership formally registered (or are you married)?  Where does your partner live now?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to answer phoog's questions.

Comment: @phoog The OP says their partner and son both live in London.

Comment: @Martin Bonner oh I see. I must have overlooked one word or another in the question.

Comment: Michael: is your son also your partner's son?  Sorry for the intrusive questions.  The goal is to determine how difficult it will be to establish that your relationship meets the UK's criteria for an unregistered partnership.

Comment: Actually @phoog, having read the question again, it isn't so clear to me.

Comment: When you say "my partner and my son both live in London". Do you mean that your son is living in London with your partner now? Or do you mean that you want to bring your son with you to live in London in the future?